# New editor and undefined control sequence error

Tags: tables, errors

For the past few years I have been using Texniccenter, but I recently changed over to Texstudio. I like the look of it a bit more. Anyway, I have run into an issue that I have no idea how to fix.

The following code "works" in Texniccenter... works as in, it spits out the errors, but still does correct thing with the table. Since it always worked Texniccenter before, I never bothered trying to figure out how to fix it. Now that I'm trying to use Texstudio, it won't even give me output, so now I need to figure it out!  =(

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{16pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.6pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
        \hline
        blah    &   -1.1    \\
        \hline
        bonk    &   2.378   \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The undefined control sequence error is at the

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.6pt} line.
```

Thanks for any sort of guidance you can give!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Editor you use (Texniccenter or texstudio) is not relevant, the error comes from the underlying latex system, and in this case the error is that `\extrarowheight` is defined by the `array` package which has not been loaded.

```
\usepackage{array}
```

will fix it.